Anime.js - apply same opacity transition in both directions in a loop
I am using Anime.js to move a square back and forth along an SVG path. The square's opacity needs to transition from 1 to 0 as it travels along the path, in both directions.
I am only able to make it transition from 1 to 0 on the forward direction, and from 0 to 1 in the reverse direction. This is the default for simple animations:
 anime({
   targets: ".square",
   translateX: path("x"),
   translateY: path("y"),
   rotate: path("angle"),
   opacity: [1, 0],
   loop: true,
   direction: 'alternate',
   easing: 'linear'
})

So I tried using a timeline:
anime.timeline({
  loop: true,
  duration: duration,
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".square",
    translateX: path("x"),
    translateY: path("y"),
    rotate: path("angle"),
    opacity: [1, 0],
    loop: true,
    direction: 'normal',
    easing: 'linear'        
  }).add({
    targets: ".square",
    translateX: path("x"),
    translateY: path("y"),
    rotate: path("angle"),
    opacity: [1, 0],
    loop: true,
    direction: 'reverse',
    easing: 'linear',  
    duration: duration,
  });
} 

... but this doesn't work because the direction parameter can only be set on the timeline object itself.
I haven't much experience with Anime.js and couldn't find anything in the docs. Would anyone be able to help with this? Thanks in advance!
https://codepen.io/Ophoph/pen/mdYNYrR

Just use opacity: 0 prop:


window.onload = function () {
    const path = anime.path("#line");
    anime.timeline({
        loop: true
    })
    .add({
        targets: "#square",
        translateX: path("x"),
        translateY: path("y"),
        opacity: [1, 0],
        easing: "linear",
        duration: 3000
    })
    .add({
        targets: "#square",
        opacity: [1, 0],
        easing: "linear",
        duration: 3000,
    translateX: 0,
        translateY: path("y"),
    });
};
.square {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path id="line" d="M 0,5 L 50,5" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1"></path>
  <rect id="square" width="4" height="4" fill="red" />
</svg>




Hi and thanks for your help. I'm trying to get the square to be always solid when it starts to move along the path, in forward and reverse directions. So, when it starts from the left, it has opacity 100, when it arrives to the right it has opacity 0, then it leaves again from the right with opacity 100 and arrives to the left with opacity 0.

Hello! OK. Updated the answer - removed the direction property. Have you read the anime.js documentation?

I have but can't find anything that helps.. the square needs to go back and forth. From right to left and then left to right and so on, so the direction "alternate" does that. But it also needs to have opacity 1 when it starts along the patch and opacity 0 when it reaches the other end, if that makes sense.

I think I finally understand what you are after ) Updated the answer

Ah amazing! Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)
